# Prove Associative Property of Multiplication (Fifth Roots of Unity)

Tags: group-theory, roots-of-unity

I have my set of elements in G (the fifth roots of unity) as {z^0, z^1, z^2, z^3, z^4} derived from de Moivre's formula. I am trying to prove G forms a group under complex multiplication. The only part I am stuck on is the Associative Property.

Since I have 5 elements, but 3 variables (a,b,c) for the associative property, I am trying to figure out how to set it up.  The only example I have found is for the third roots of unity. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: already for the larger set of complex numbers, multiplication is associative ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that *for any* $a,b,c\in G$, $(ab)c = a(bc)$.

To see this, note that when you multiply different powers of $z$, you add the exponents, and addition is associative.

Comment: Thank you.  Using your tip I figured it out.